# Android cannot delete parse installation

Tags: android, parse-platform

I use parse to handle push notification. Because I already have my own database, I use parse to store installation data only.(Not using ParseUser to login and logout in the app)
When I logout my app, I would like to delete my installation.

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ParseInstallation deleteInBackground done");
        if (ex != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ParseInstallation deleteInBackground", ex);
        }
    }
});
```

Then I got the following error:

```
com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: forbidden
        at com.parse.ParseRequest.newPermanentException(ParseRequest.java:391)
        at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponse(ParseRESTCommand.java:197)
        at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:258)
        at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:254)
        at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
        at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
        at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
        at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
        at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:610)
        at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:702)
        at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:690)
        at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm unable to understand what you're trying to achieve. The installation class, as by name, is meant to store the installations of your app. Continuing... a new installation object is created every time you call initialise(key1, key2) for the first time.

Comment: I would like to delete the installation record which is store in parse. So that the user will no receive any push notifications.

Comment: For push notifications? Did you subscribe the users logged in to a channel?

Comment: Here's a solution. When a user logins, subscribe them to a channel, for example "logged_in". And when they logout, unsubscribe them from the same channel. Lastly, for push notifications, only send them to the people subscribed to that channel. This way, only the logged in users will receive push notifications.

Comment: adding to what @Aashir said, another option would be to extend ParsePushBroadcastReceiver and handle the push in a different way, for example if they are online/offline just don't show it. deleting is pretty much overkill.

Comment: Does unsubscribe detach Parse association to that device? In other words, if you log into the same device as two different users, unsubscribe works better than ParseUser.logout when trying to clear data to prepare for the user to login again?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to make a request with a user who doesn't have enough authorizathion to do it.
Maybe, you are doing this request when the session is already destroyed(for logout),instead of doing it before destroying it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete it from Cloud Code using master key.

In the android client:

```
                //clear the installation backend
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            String idToken = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getInstallationId();
            params.put("installationId", idToken);
            ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("removeInstallation", params, new FunctionCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void done(String response, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        //clear the local chache
                        ParseEasyAccess.clearParse();
                    } else {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

And then in the Cloud Code:

```
         Parse.Cloud.define("removeInstallation", function(request, response) {

         Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

         var installationId = request.params.installationId;

         var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
         query.equalTo("installationId", installationId);

         query.find(function(installations) {
             installations[0].destroy().then(
                 function() {
                     response.success("Destroyed");
                 },
                 function() {
                     response.error("Failed");
                 });
         });

     });
```

And if you wish to also delete the cached Installation on your device, do the following:

1. Create a package named com.parse
2. Crate a class, like for example MyParseTools.
3. Make a static method liks so:

   ```
   public static void clearParseInstallation() {
   ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallationController().clearFromDisk();
   ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallationController().clearFromMemory();}
   ```